# custom post type section selector

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type which is named products. Each product will have overview/details/pricing.

How can i make a navigation inside my post-type  for each field?
Example:

- Product 1: (Custom Post Type Product)

  - Overview/Details/Pricing (Custom Fields i guess)

On overview click i want to display an overview for the product, (maybe use a child page and load into the overview field? )

I'm really confused, can anyone help?

Comment: You could create a repeater field with 2 fields; 1) title 2) link (to create a menu).
Then you loop through that which outputs the links you have entered. 

You can create 'fake subpages' which retrieve the info from the product post or create actual subpages and enter the info there.

Comment: @Beee can you explain that a little bit more with an example please? I'm really struggling to get into this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as requested.

Create an ACF field.
Add a repeater field.
Inside the repeater, add a text field with name title.
Inside the repeater, add an URL field with name link.

```
$menu_items = get_field( 'repeater_field' )

if ( $menu_items ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach( $menu_items as $item ) {
        echo '<li><a href="{{ item.link }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

You can then link to any sub-pages you have created.

Comment: repeater fields are now available only on pro version..

Comment: Buy the pro version. It's only 25 bucks but it's worth its weight in gold. It's by far the best WP plugin I ever bought ! And they're about to release a new version with a lot more options. It will make your website so much easier to manage.

Comment: I can use normal fields, to do my job in this case, every page of my custom post type has the same fields, so why not?

Comment: Then I can't help you sorry. I have never used the free version.

Comment: i found an easier solution using load() function of jquery and normal fields! thanks anyway.